# KRunner won't find certain files

Tags: kubuntu, search, indexing, baloo, krunner

KRunner on my Kubuntu 19.10 won't find certain files, in particular, files with a .tex extension.

The file search and places plugins in the KRunner settings are activated, the directores I am interested in are not excluded in the file search settings, and other files, such as .log files in the same directories, are found by the KRunner search.

In the baloo configuration, I removed `application/x-tex` from the excluded MIME types and made sure that `*.tex` is not among the excluded filters, and re-built the index. Asking to index individual .tex files returns "File already indexed", and the baloo search in Dolphin finds .tex files as well, so the issue does not (or no longer) seem to be on the side of baloo. However, even after a reboot, KRunner search will still not find these files.

Initially, my suspicion was .tex files were not indexed before my baloo configuration change and re-indexing, and KRunner somehow failed to recognize the updated index and is still using the old baloo data in which .tex files are not listed. "Clear history" in the KRunner settings did not help. However, newly created files are found as well, so an outdated index is apparently not the problem either.

What else could cause this issue? Is there some KRunner setting I'm missing?